How do parentheses work in Lambda Calculus Reduction?
Okay so I'm just learning some lambda calculus and I came across this problem.
Perform reduction on this - if it cannot be reduced then say it will diverge
(λy.(λx.xx)y)(λx.x)
These are the steps I tried following.
(λy.(λx.xx)y)(λx.x) [1]
(λy.(xx)[x:=y])(λx.x) [2] Beta Reduction
(λy.yy)(λx.x) [2]
(yy)[y:=λx.x] [3] Beta Reduction
(λx.x)(λx.x) [3]
(λx.x)(λx'.x')[4] Alpha Reduction
(x)[x:=λx'.x')[5] Beta Reduction
(λx'.x')[6] Final Reduction.

I've then tried to confirm my answer using a calculator online and apparently the final answer should be.
= xx
The steps they took were:
(λy.(λx.xx)y)(λx.x)
(λy.xx)(λx'.x') - Beta Reduction
xx - Beta Reduction


If somebody could let me know where I went wrong I'd appreciate it!

This sounds like a question that is more suitable for Computer Science Stack Exchange. However, before posting there, do check their rules and expectations.

Your answer of (λx.x) is correct. You reduced the inner lambda first but you could've started with the outer and arrived at the same answer. (No alpha renaming necessary). See also evaluation strategy.

@Mulan so is the calculator answer incorrect?

@Priit yes the first step is already incorrect

You didn't go wrong. Your result is correct:
(λy.(λx.xx)y)(λx.x) =
(λy.    yy  )(λx.x) =
   (λx.x)(λx.x)     =
       (λx.x)

